# How to debug a build version of the code

Tags: debugging, sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I am using Sencha Touch and the development and testing version of code works fine but there is some error thrown on the console when I am running the build, but I dont know how to debug the production build. Can anyone help me, how do we debug the build of the code.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you mean to ask how to debug the production build running on an emulator or device?

Answer (score 0):

Look for any "debugger".  The production build will fail if there are any debugger in your code.